# Trouble creating a file in android and writing to it. Unhandled exception java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "hello world!";
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}
```

I don't really know what's wrong. I get errors on new FileOutpuStream(file), fos.write(...),and fos.close().

I apologize for the simple question as I am new to Java and Android.

Comment: Why FileNotFoundException occurs --- http://craftingjava.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/file-not-found-exception-file-not-found.html

Comment: test.txt doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

For saving file:

```
public void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fou = openFileOutput("data.txt", MODE_APPEND);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fou);
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

For loading file:

```
public String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("data.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add codes to handle IOException (not only FileNotFoundException). Either catch it or throw it. Here is an example of throwing it using `throws IOException` (I have tested the code and it runs as expected):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String string = "hello world!";
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}
```